# Print Length of String Value in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, string-length

I have a list called `movies` that contains dictionaries that include key: value pairs such as title, description, genre, etc. I want to be able to find the string length of the description of a given movie within that list

Here is what I've tried

```
def get_movie_description_length(dictionary_entry):
  print(len(dictionary_entry['description']))

get_movie_description_length('The Godfather')
```

It throws

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I adjust the code to make this work?

I was expecting it to return the integer 149 as that is the length of the string that is the value to the key `'description'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# toy dataset
movies = [
    {
        'title': 'The Shawshank Redemption',
        'description': 'Two imprisoned men bond over several years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.',
        'genre': 'Drama'
    },
    {
        'title': 'Inception',
        'description': 'A thief who steals corporate secrets through the use of dream-sharing technology is given the inverse task of planting an idea into the mind of a CEO.',
        'genre': 'Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi'
    },
    {
        'title': 'Pulp Fiction',
        'description': 'The lives of two mob hitmen, a boxer, a gangster and his wife, and a pair of diner bandits intertwine in four tales of violence and redemption.',
        'genre': 'Crime, Drama'
    },
    {
        'title': 'The Dark Knight',
        'description': 'When the menace known as the Joker wreaks havoc and chaos on the people of Gotham, Batman must accept one of the greatest psychological and physical tests of his ability to fight injustice.',
        'genre': 'Action, Crime, Drama'
    },
    {
        'title': 'The Matrix',
        'description': 'A computer hacker learns from mysterious rebels about the true nature of his reality and his role in the war against its controllers.',
        'genre': 'Action, Sci-Fi'
    }
]


def get_description_length(movie_title):
    for movie in movies:
        if movie['title'] == movie_title:
            return len(movie['description'])
    return 0  # Return 0 if the movie title is not found in the dataset

print(get_description_length('The Matrix'))
```

If the data was instead a dictionary:

```
movies = {
    'The Shawshank Redemption': {
        'description': 'Two imprisoned men bond over several years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.',
        'genre': 'Drama'
    },
    'Inception': {
        'description': 'A thief who steals corporate secrets through the use of dream-sharing technology is given the inverse task of planting an idea into the mind of a CEO.',
        'genre': 'Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi'
    },
    'Pulp Fiction': {
        'description': 'The lives of two mob hitmen, a boxer, a gangster and his wife, and a pair of diner bandits intertwine in four tales of violence and redemption.',
        'genre': 'Crime, Drama'
    },
    'The Dark Knight': {
        'description': 'When the menace known as the Joker wreaks havoc and chaos on the people of Gotham, Batman must accept one of the greatest psychological and physical tests of his ability to fight injustice.',
        'genre': 'Action, Crime, Drama'
    },
    'The Matrix': {
        'description': 'A computer hacker learns from mysterious rebels about the true nature of his reality and his role in the war against its controllers.',
        'genre': 'Action, Sci-Fi'
    }
}
```

then something like this would work:

```
def get_movie_description_length(dictionary_entry):
  print(len(movies[dictionary_entry]['description']))

get_movie_description_length('The Matrix')
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, it works! But looking at that, I don't understand why *dictionary_entry['description']* in my one doesn't work, but *movie['description']* in your one does, is that because it's part of the loop? Dictionaries and For Loops are something that I struggle with as I'm learning Python

Comment: without seeing your code, it's hard to say, but if you are running it on the list, then the list doesn't have keys, and it's going to fail

Comment: As far as I can tell (the code is part of a course I'm doing), it would look like *movie = [{title: x, description: y, genre: z}, etc]*... would there be a way to do this without any iteration? ie you could just plug in a title into the function argument and it would retrieve the string length? Or does that have to be done in a for loop... apologies if that doesn't make sense

Comment: if the list was instead a dictionary, then the function you created would probably work. But because you have structured it as a list, that kind of syntax doesn't work

Comment: yeah, if you were to have it be a dictionary, the keys could be the movie names, and the values could be a list of attributes (e.g. description, year, rating etc.)

Comment: I added a bit more to the answer to help illustrate